# How to replace existing sqlite database file with new database file in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Im doing an app which uses sqlite database There is an feature in my app having a button 'Update Database'.

When user clicks on the 'Update Database' button i need to upgrade the old db file with new db file from URL.

How to do this. the research tells me that we cant change a db as it gets place in an .apk file.
Is there any solution to this.
Please help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 5):

```
private void importDatabase(String inputFileName) throws IOException
{
    InputStream mInput = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
    String outFileName = YOUR_DB_PATH_HERE;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
    {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}
```

**EDIT:**

You may find it helpfull:

[How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728)

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Note for others. I allowed for restoration with the exact same code. Its a simple copy this file function after all.

Comment: The new db file acts as if it was empty but it is not, I cannot find any data on it

Comment: @Jesus , this issue started hapening recently, did you find a way around it

Answer (score 3):

Simply you could download the db file from URL using Download Manager and copy the file to this path

```
         /data/data/<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>/databases/
```

It will automatically update.I have used this and is working

Comment: He is saying to copy the data directly into the directory for the application. The foo.db file for your app is in the directory pattern above. However in my case, I do not have a rooted device so I will not be able to access the databse folder. You might be able to just make a new one. I solved it with simple IO, the the other answer.

Comment: Should I also do something with "<database>.db-journal" file in there, like remove it?

Comment: These are temporary files created . They will be deleted by itself.

Answer (score 1):

At the first launch of your application, you should copy your database into external/internal storage, out of the apk file. 
When you need to update (with statements or by replacing the whole db) you can operate in the internal/external memory without problems.
When you update your application (and maybe the new application has a new db inside), at the first launch of the new app, you should replace the db you stored in the internal/external memory.